# Override class in setup:upgrade command in magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, setup, setup-upgrade, command

I am trying to override the class `FilePermissions` (`magento/framework/Setup/FilePermissions.php`) but my changes are not taken in account while I use the `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I tried :

- To add a new preference in my di.xml, but the rewrite is not taken in account
- To use a plugin instead of a rewrite but it didn't work either

It seem that the module `Magento_Setup` have some particular behavior compared to other modules in term of bootstrapping.

Does anyone succeed to override method during magento `setup` command ?

Thank for your help

Comment: Give us a good reason would you do that with setup upgrade?

Comment: @AndréFerraz, I would like to change the way to check file permission for some sub directory of `var`. I got some big directory that Magento don't need to check.

Comment: @PierreGauthier did you find any solution for this?